# What does it mean to end a sentence with ひとつだけ?

Tags: word-requests, word-usage, sentence-final-particles, particle-だけ

I came across a sentence that ends with ひとつだけ in a book and searching on jisho gave me zero results ([https://jisho.org/search/ひとつだけ](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A4%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91)); nor did searching for the individual parsing of what I remember from the audio of the VN (i.e. hitotsu--DakE) give me any helpful results that would make sense in context.

> しかも、出入り口は錆の浮いた鉄扉が**ひとつだけ**。

TDLR: What does the sentence end(?) ひとつだけ mean in the above context and does it have a general meaning when used at the end of a sentence as opposed to being used elsewhere in the sentence?

Edit:

Context: Narrator is describing a unfamiliar room he wakes up in.
I think that ひとつだけ in the above context will not work as individual parsings as ひとつ most likely means either the "adverbial noun – just" or the numeric one in the above context that adverbially/numerically describes the 鉄扉 (iron door). The next bit, だけ most likely is a particle ("only") but I don't see how the "only" can affect the 鉄扉 as the ひとつ is already doing that to the "iron door". 
The only way I can see both affecting 鉄扉 is if ひとつだけ is a qualifier sentence (technically a qualifier phrase) being used in reverse-order.

Comment: Try appending です at the end -- does it make more sense now?

Comment: @psosuna I think of ひとつだけです but it still does not make sense, as my main issue is that the sentence just, kind of, ends with a particle that Jishio does not confirm to be a sentence-end particle that can also mean the same thing as  ひとつ, meaning it could be "only only", "just one", "only one", etc... Maybe I'm overthinking it again.

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Can you tell us what you think the context is and why you think the individual parsings do not make sense?

Comment: @Ringil, yeah, I'll do it in a edit to my question.

Comment: I think it means 出入り口は錆の浮いた鉄扉がひとつだけ**ある**, with ある being omitted.

Comment: ^ 「しかも出入口は鉄扉が一つだけある。」って、おかしいと思うんですけど。。「 しかも**出入口は** 鉄扉(が)一つ**だけだ** 。」ならいいですが。 「もはや食料は、おにぎりが一つだけあった。」がおかしいのと同じで・・・。「もはや食料は、おにぎり(が)一つだけだった。」ならいいですけど。

Comment: @Chocolate If I am translating your comment correctly (ごめんなさい for any mistakes, I am still a beginner of the Japanese language), 
"「しかも出入口は鉄扉が一つだけある。」 appears to be a strange thought to me. It would be better to be「しかも出入口は 鉄扉(が)一つだけだ 。」.  I find it strange written as 「もはや食料は、おにぎりが一つだけあった。」..... I'm certain 「もはや食料は、おにぎり(が)一つだけだった。」 is better." is what you meant in replying to Sweeper?

Comment: はい, I meant to say...　しかも出入口は鉄扉が一つだけある sounds strange/unnatural to me. しかも出入口は 鉄扉(が)一つだけだ  would be fine/natural, though..  It's similar to how (or, For the same reason as why(?)) もはや食料は、おにぎりが一つだけあった sounds strange/unnatural. もはや食料は、おにぎり(が)一つだけだった would be fine/natural. (... Sorry, I didn't know how to say がおかしいのと同じで in English.. (T.T)

Answer (score 7):

Consider these simpler examples:

> - リンゴ**は**2個です。
>     The number of apples is two.
> - 参加者**は**3人です。
>     The number of participants is three.
> - 「箱の中には何がありますか？」「バナナ**が**2本です。」
>     "What is in the box?" "Two bananas."

Although "Apples are two" makes no sense in English, リンゴは2個です is a perfectly valid way to tell the number of things in Japanese. As you already know, the topic marker は is used for things already in the universe of discourse. が is used to introduce a new item into the universe of discourse.

You can use both は and が at the same time:

> 参加者**は**日本人**が**3人です。
>   Regarding (the number of) participants, there are three Japanese people.

You can drop です/だ to make a sentence look more compact and/or dramatic (体言止め):

> 参加者は3人。
>   (There are) three participants.

You can add だけ (or のみ) to add the meaning of "only".

> 参加者は3人**だけ**です。
>   The number of participants is only three.

Combined together, we have something like:

> 参加者は日本人が3人だけ。
>   Regarding participants, there are only three Japanese people.

This is exactly how your sentence in question is constructed, too.

Comment: Veery clear as usual, thanks! Is it possible to use existence verbs (ある/いる) in (some of) these sentences? If so, what makes them different from the OP’s sentences?