# How is "ひとつな" used here?

Tags: translation

Read this on a japanese article.

> 明日が休日なら僕と君二人きり。
>   する事はひとつな訳で

Does it still mean like the counter "ひとつ” here. Something like "one thing I want to do."?

Am I missing from my understanding here? I've only just learned how わけない is used.

> Since tomorrow's a holiday, it'll just be the two of us. There's one thing I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

する事はひとつだ means "the number of things to do is one", or more naturally, "there is only one thing to do". See: [What does it mean to end a sentence with ひとつだけ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65911/5010)

～な訳だ/～という訳だ roughly means "naturally", "as a consequence" or "it's that ～", see: [How to end a sentence in わけ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2250/5010) And で is used instead of だ after 訳 because of [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11950/5010).

> する事はひとつな訳で。
>   Naturally, there's only one thing to do (together).
>   Of course there is only one thing we should do.